# Grpc-gateway: how to deal with non-json request body?

Tags: go, grpc-gateway

Grpc-gateway offers solutions for customizing response body using `google.api.HttpBody` (non-json content type like `text/plain`, `application/xml`, etc), however, this proto message cannot deal with request body.

Comment: Does this address your question https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/blob/869d32e2f0af2748ab530646053b23a2b80d9ca5/google/api/http.proto#L61-L87

Comment: @SanP Nope. It only addresses how to read request parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by [johanbrandhorst' comment](https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/issues/7#issuecomment-1088176696), I came up with a solution with a customized marshaler. I implemented interfaces of [runtime.marshaler](https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/blob/master/runtime/marshaler.go#L8) to create my own marshaler.

**Custiomized marshaler**

```
package marshaler

import (
    "errors"
    "io"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "reflect"

    "github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/v2/runtime"
    "google.golang.org/genproto/googleapis/api/httpbody"
)

type XMLMarshaler struct {
    runtime.Marshaler
}

func (x XMLMarshaler) ContentType(_ interface{}) string {
    return "application/xml"
}

func (x XMLMarshaler) Marshal(v interface{}) ([]byte, error) {
    log.Println("xml marshal")
    log.Printf("param: %+v", v)
    // return xml.Marshal(v)
    if httpBody, ok := v.(*httpbody.HttpBody); ok {
        return httpBody.Data, nil
    }
    return x.Marshaler.Marshal(v)
}

func (x XMLMarshaler) NewDecoder(r io.Reader) runtime.Decoder {
    log.Println("xml new decoder")
    return runtime.DecoderFunc(func(p interface{}) error {
        buffer, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }

        pType := reflect.TypeOf(p)
        if pType.Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
            v := reflect.Indirect(reflect.ValueOf(p))
            if v.Kind() == reflect.String {
                v.Set(reflect.ValueOf(string(buffer)))
                return nil
            }
        }
        return errors.New("value type error")
    })
}
```

**starting grpc-gateway**

```
func run() error {
    ctx := context.Background()
    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(ctx)
    defer cancel()

    // Register gRPC server endpoint
    // Note: Make sure the gRPC server is running properly and accessible
    mux := runtime.NewServeMux(
        runtime.WithMarshalerOption("application/xml", marshaler.XMLMarshaler{}),
    )
    opts := []grpc.DialOption{grpc.WithTransportCredentials(insecure.NewCredentials())}
    err := gw.RegisterBotServiceHandlerFromEndpoint(ctx, mux, *grpcServerEndpoint, opts)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    // Start HTTP server (and proxy calls to gRPC server endpoint)
    return http.ListenAndServe(":8080", mux)
}
```

Then, for all requests with content type specified as "application/xml", `grpc-gateway` will assign the XML body data to [google.api.HttpBody.Data](https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/blob/869d32e2f0af2748ab530646053b23a2b80d9ca5/google/api/httpbody.proto#L72). And, for non-json responses, `grpc-gateway` will  assign [google.api.HttpBody.Data](https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/blob/869d32e2f0af2748ab530646053b23a2b80d9ca5/google/api/httpbody.proto#L72) to response body.